# Unable to persist address in browser URL bar, during PHP 302 Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-302

On my page

```
/my/conditional/redirect/page/index.php
```

I have a conditional **PHP 302 Redirect**:

```
<?php

if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['369.168.492.123'])) {

  // header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/my/redirect/index.php', TRUE, 302);
  exit;
}

else {

  [... PHP CODE HERE...]
}

?>
```

I have tried this code:

- as above
- with and without the `TRUE` and `302` parameters
- with and without `exit;`
- with and without `https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

No matter. The redirect always changes the location in the browser URL bar to:

```
/my/redirect/index.php
```

while I would greatly prefer it to persist as:

```
/my/conditional/redirect/page/index.php
```

What am I missing to ensure the page redirects (via a `302 Redirect`) without the browser URL bar location updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing to ensure the page redirects (via a 302 Redirect) without the browser URL bar location updating?

Nothing. That's how HTTP redirects work.

If you want to preserve the URL, then you need to perform an *internal* redirect or a proxy request so that the server returns the content you want for the URL that was requested.

Comment: Okay. There maybe something I've misunderstood here. I always do my redirects in `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite`. 98% of the time the redirects I deploy are `301` redirects which update the location in the browser URL bar. But I understand I can also deploy `302` redirects _and_ redirects which don't update the location in the browser URL bar. For clarification, is it the case that PHP redirects don't allow for all four of these options that `mod_rewrite` allows for? Many thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You've misunderstood the difference between 301 and 302. 301 is permanent. 302 is temporary. The difference is that a client is supposed to update it's records about the URL if it hits a 301 (e.g. a search engine is supposed to direct people directly to the new URL for a 301).

Comment: PHP can output 301 and 302 HTTP redirects using the `header` function. It can proxy a request to a different URL with, for example, cURL.

Comment: mod_rewrite can issue redirects `[R]` but doesn't have to and will do an internal redirect if you omit that (and Apache HTTPD will then just serve up the other resource from the original URL).

Comment: No, as I said "It can proxy a request to a different URL with, for example, cURL."

Comment: Apologies in advance, some of this vocabulary is new to me. When you write _"internal redirect"_ and _"proxy request"_, do you intend these to be synonyms of each other or are you referring to two explicitly different things, which deliver approximately the same result?

Comment: There's no difference from outside the webserver. From inside, the differences are subtle. In one your code makes an HTTP request to a URL and returns the result to the client. In the other, the server handles the original request as if it were to a different URL.

Comment: Okay, so basically the conclusion is that I cannot initiate with PHP the kind of _internal redirect_ that I would initiate with `mod_rewrite`. I'm not keen to use `cURL` in this situation, so I think I'll try and solve my issue with an `include` instead. Thanks for all your time on this, helping me to understand how not everything that can be achieved with `mod_rewrite` redirects can be achieved with PHP `header('Location: [...]' );`